# How to construct abstractly and symmetrically the map $^{n+k}M⊗^kN→^nM$ given a pairing $M⊗N→R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M,N$ be $R$-modules.

Let $\langle-,-\rangle$ be a pairing $M⊗N→R$. We can construct a pairing $\Lambda^kM⊗\Lambda^kN→R$ by sending $(a_1∧⋯∧a_k)⊗(b_1∧⋯∧b_k)$ to $\det(\langle a_i, b_j \rangle)_{ij}$.
We can more generally construct a map $\Lambda^{n+k} M ⊗ \Lambda^n N → \Lambda^k M$ that can be defined recursively by
$$ \langle a_1∧⋯∧a_{n+k}, b_1∧⋯∧b_k \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n+k} (-1)^{i-1} \langle a_i,b_1\rangle \langle a_1∧⋯∧\widehat{a_i}∧⋯∧a_{n+k}, b_2∧⋯∧b_k \rangle $$
where $\widehat{a_i}$ means that $a_i$ is omitted. The result is a sum over all injections $f : [\![1,k]\!] → [\![1,n+k]\!]$ of $$± \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^k \langle a_{f(i)}, b_i \rangle \bigg) \bigwedge_{j \not\in \operatorname{image}(f)} a_j.$$

Bourbaki gives an abstract construction of these maps as follows, but it is not symmetrical and I don't know how to prove the symmetry of the definition without referring to the formula. Here is the construction of Bourbaki (Algèbre III):

We start by defining a coalgebra structure on $\Lambda M$ by applying $\Lambda$ to the coalgebra structure on $M$ given by the diagonal $M→M⊕M$ and the zero map $M→0$. We get a comultiplication $\Lambda M → \Lambda(M⊕M) = \Lambda M ⊗ \Lambda M$ and a counit $\Lambda M→0=R$. Dualizing degreewise this structure, we get an algebra structure on the graded dual
$$(\Lambda M)' = \bigoplus_{k=0}^∞ (\Lambda^k M)^*.$$ This is an anticommutative alternating graded algebra (which can be deduced from the fact that $\Lambda M → \Lambda (M⊕M)$ is a morphism of algebras, without computation), so by the universal property of $\Lambda (M^*)$, the morphism $M^* → (\Lambda M)'$ gives an algebra morphism $\Lambda (M^*) → (\Lambda M)'$ and thus an action on $\Lambda M$.

So this construction gives the pairing $\Lambda^k M ⊗ \Lambda^k M^* → R$ and if we have a morphism $N→M^*$, we can deduce the pairing $\Lambda^k M ⊗ \Lambda^k N → \Lambda^k M ⊗ \Lambda^k M^* → R$.

Is there an other abstract construction that is more symmetrical than Bourbaki's?

PS: I include the tag "category theory" because perhaps people watching this tag know an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that  $\wedge M $ is an $R$ algebra with the following universal property: we have the map $m \mapsto m \in \wedge^1(M) \simeq M$, and $m^2=0$ in $\wedge M$. Moreover, whenever we have an $R$ algebra $A$ and an $R$ linear map from $M$ to $A$ such that any $m$ maps to an element of square $0$, then there exists a map... ( a particular case of Clifford algebra, when the quadratic form is $0$). Now, you need to know how to take the graded tensor products of graded commutative algebras. Once you know that, you know what is $\wedge M \otimes \wedge M$, another graded commutative algebra. Now consider the $R$ linear map from $M$ to $\wedge M \otimes \wedge M$, $m \mapsto m\otimes 1 + 1\otimes m$. Note that we have
$$( m\otimes 1 + 1\otimes m)( m\otimes 1 + 1\otimes m)= m\wedge m \otimes 1 + m \otimes m - m \otimes m + 1 \otimes m \wedge m = 0$$
We conclude there exists a morphism of $R$ algebras
$$\wedge M \to (\wedge M )\otimes (\wedge M)\\
m \mapsto m \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes m$$

Let's calculate for instance the image of $m_1 \wedge m_2 \wedge m_3$. We have
$$m_1 \wedge m_2 \wedge m_3\mapsto ( m_1 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes m_1)( m_2 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes m_2)(m_3 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes m_3) = \\=m_1 \wedge m_2 \wedge m_3\otimes 1  +  (m_1 \wedge m_2 \otimes m_3 + m_2 \wedge m_3 \otimes m_1  +  m_3 \wedge m_1 \otimes m_2) + \\+(\cdots )+ 1 \otimes m_1 \wedge m_2 \wedge m_3$$

We can describe the image of an element $m_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge m_l$. The rule of signs is like the one for the Laplace expansion. The important thing is that globally the permutation across the $\otimes$ sign is even. I hope it is clear enough.

Now, the algebra $\wedge M \otimes \wedge M$ is bi-graded. So we have maps from
$$(\wedge M \otimes \wedge M)^{n+k} \to \wedge^k M \otimes \wedge^n M$$   This gets us an $R$ linear  map
$$\wedge^{n+k} M \to \wedge^k M \otimes \wedge^n M$$
From the above it should be clear what this map is. We used the graded tensor product of $\wedge M$ with itself  to justify that the map is OK, and the correct form. Otherwise, one can just take it as a definition. Anyways, this linear map gets us a linear map
$$\wedge^{n+k} M \otimes \wedge^k N \to \wedge^k M \otimes \wedge^n M\otimes \wedge^k N$$

But we have a linear map
$$\wedge^k M \otimes \wedge^k N\to R\\
(m_1 \wedge\ldots\wedge m_k) \otimes (n_1 \wedge\ldots\wedge n_k) \mapsto \det( \langle m_i, n_j\rangle)$$

Now compose and we get our desired map.

We should also mention the following important fact that shows that one can define the interior product inductively. Say we have $\alpha \in \wedge^{n+k_1+ k_n}$, $\beta_i\in \wedge^{k_i}N$, $i=1,2$. Denote the pairing
$ \wedge^{n+k}M \otimes \wedge^k N \to \wedge^n M$ by
$(\alpha, \beta) \mapsto \alpha\Finv \beta$. Then we have
$$\alpha\Finv(\beta_1\wedge \beta_2) = (\alpha\Finv \beta_1) \Finv\beta_2$$
This follows from the Laplace expansion of determinants.

$\bf{Added:}$ We can see that $\Finv \beta$ is the adjoint of $\beta \wedge \cdot $  on the $N$ side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though my question would be to construct this map 
$(m_1 \wedge\ldots\wedge m_k) \otimes (n_1 \wedge\ldots\wedge n_k) \mapsto \det( \langle m_i, n_j\rangle)$
in a way that is both abstract (as done in Bourbaki) *and* symmetrical (as the determinant formula), or to show abstractly that the construction of Bourbaki is symmetrical. As a side note, the map $M → M ⊗ M$ that you define is the map $M → (M⊕M) ≅ M ⊗ M$ used by Bourbaki.

Comment: @Idéophage: You are welcome!  Now, the determinant formula is symmetric since we know that the determinant of the transpose is the determinant of a matrix. Apriori it may not look symmetric.  Yes, the formula with the wedge of the sum is true, but we can pretend not to know it, and just use the graded tensor product.